# concatenate data bind in dropdown using linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, concatenation, dropdown

i have table where i select data and there is 3 columns i merge or concatenate these columns.. query and data is

```
 Select (Region+'    '+cast(StartDate+''+EndDate as varchar)) as data,ID from tblRegion_Uni
```

data

```
 data                           ID
UK    Mar 31 2128 11:59PM       1
US    Mar 31 2128 11:59PM       2
Paris Mar 31 2128 11:59PM       3
```

now i try to bind this data in dropdown using linq but i want above sql query in linq .. below linq query simple select the data but i want also concatenate in linq

```
private List<tblRegion_Uni> getregion()
    {
   using(TrackDataEntities1 tee=new TrackDataEntities1())
         {
             return (from ta in tee.tblReg select new { ta.Region, ta.StartDate, ta.EndDate }).ToList();

         }

    }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            regiondrop.DataSource = getregion();
            regiondrop.DataTextField = "data";
            regiondrop.DataValueField = "id";
            regiondrop.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

when i try this error occur

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<chart_project.tblRegion_Uni>`'

any solution?

Comment: Basically, your method signature says that the method returns `List<tblRegion_Uni>` while the body actually returns list of anonymous typed object (`return new { ... }`), that's what the error message trying to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are working with data in your database, and your data has special nullable values, It can't get filtered and then bring them to your memory so you need to firstly bring datas to your memory and then make whatever you want.

Create a new ViewModel class with property that you want:

```
public static class MyList{
    public static int Id {get; set;}
    public static string Data {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your code, where you want to get suitable data make this method:

```
private List<MyList> getregion()
    {
       using(TrackDataEntities1 tee=new TrackDataEntities1())
         {
             var tempList=tee.tblReg.ToList();
             var list=(from ta in tempList
                      let data = ta.Region + " " + ta.StartDate??DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ta.EndDate??DateTime.Now.ToString() 
                      select new{data, ta.ID}).Select(x=> new MyList{
                      Id=x.ID,
                      Data=x.data}).ToList();
             return list;
         }

    }
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
         regiondrop.DataSource = getregion();
         regiondrop.DataTextField = "Data";
         regiondrop.DataValueField = "Id";
         regiondrop.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: i use this on page laod ??? var list=(from ta in tee.tblReg
         let data = ta.Region + "   " + ta.StartDate + " " + ta.EndDate
         select new{data, ta.ID}).ToDictionary(x=>x.ID, x=>x.data);

Comment: when i use this on page load .. following error occur Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Comment: Can Region or StartDate or EndDate be null? Is your field type nullable?

Comment: field type is Startdate (datetime,null)

Comment: enddate type also same e.g. (datetime , null) and region(varchar(50),null)

Comment: means this line get data from database.. var tempList=tee.tblReg.ToList();

Comment: @user6408005 Exactly, Because you want to do something special you need to bring them to your memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i haven't tested the code

```
private List<tblRegion_Uni> getregion()
    {
   using(TrackDataEntities1 tee=new TrackDataEntities1())
         {
             return (from ta in tee.tblReg select new { ta.Region, ta.StartDate, ta.EndDate }).ToList();

         }

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            regiondrop.DataSource = getregion();
            regiondrop.DataTextField = "data";
            regiondrop.DataValueField = "ID";
            regiondrop.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

i think you have to specifically say , which column to bind...

Comment: PLEASE CHECK UPDATE QUESTION

Comment: Did it work , have you tried, i cant test , i work on MVC framework

Comment: But i don't see the binding , where is the Concatenated binding done , code

Comment: the code looks confusing to me, something is missing,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your error is giving you a solid clue as to what the problem is.

Your page/view is expecting a model of type `List<chart_project.tblRegion_Uni>` but you are providing a `List<T>` where T is an anonymous type.

Generally something like this forces you to explicitly cast the variable, or in example below I use linq to bind the object:

Although I have a bad feeling about this...
Try changing that one line of code to:

```
return (from ta in tee.tblReg select new { ta.Region, ta.StartDate, ta.EndDate }).
Select(x => new chart_project.tblRegion_Uni
{
data = $"{ta.Region.ToString()} {ta.StartDate.ToString() {ta.EndDate.Tostring()"
}).ToList();
```

*I kinda guessed at your ViewModel variables, **hope this helps***

This may not work properly...but ideally you would set and/or control the object to return (so chart_project.tblRegion_Uni would be a class with 1 property ["ViewModel"])

*Sorry if this doesn't do it for you :(*

Comment: i want to concatenate region start date and enddate and place in one column .. how i do this as i explain in question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private dynamic getregion()
{
  using(TrackDataEntities1 tee=new TrackDataEntities1())
  {
    return (from ta in tee.tblReg select new { ID = ta.YourColumn,DisplayText = ta.Region+ta.StartDate.ToShortDateString()+ ta.EndDate.ToShortDateString() }).ToList();

  }

}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    regiondrop.DataSource = getregion();
    regiondrop.DataTextField = "DisplayText";
    regiondrop.DataValueField = "ID";
    regiondrop.DataBind();

  }
}
```

Comment: i think this simple select data .. List<tblReg > list = tee.tblReg.ToList();.. i want to concatenate columns

Comment: @user6408005 see the updated answer you will need to specify the coulmn name for your `DataTextFeild `in ID feild

Comment: why you use dynamic?

Comment: Because the list being selected is of anonymus type and can't be casted to List<tblregion_uni>

Comment: Yes i know this code works fine i have tested it ? Have you tried this ?

Comment: this shows error  Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Comment: Have you replaced the `ta.YourColumnName` with actual columnNmae ?

Comment: Also check if you have null values in your database for StartDate and Enddate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114408/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-user6408005).

Comment: NO THERE IS NO NULL VALUE

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Object> getregion()
    {
   using(TrackDataEntities1 tee=new TrackDataEntities1())
         {
             return (from ta in tee.tblReg select new { Id = ta.ID, Data = ta.Region+ " " +ta.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")+ " "+ta.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") }).ToList();

         }

    }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            regiondrop.DataSource = getregion();
            regiondrop.DataTextField = "Data";
            regiondrop.DataValueField = "Id";
            regiondrop.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Comment: errors: Error 4 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments
Error 5 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments 
Error 3 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: damn... that was a quick shot. But the object list should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        **regiondrop.DataSource = getregion();
        regiondrop.DataTextField = "data";//it show in dropdown
        regiondrop.DataValueField = "ID";//pass value
        regiondrop.DataBind();**
```